For $p\geq 2$ show that $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is irreducible
For $p\geq 2$ show that $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ where $f(x)=x^p-x+c$ is irreducible for all nonzero $c$. And separable.
My approach:
First for irreducibility, notice $f(z)=0 \iff p | f(z)$. And since $c\notin \overline{p}$ for $z\neq c$, $p $ do not divide $f(z)$ because it doesnt divide the constant term. For $z=c$ then $f(z)=0 \iff p | c^p$ but $p$ do not divide $c$ hence it cant divide its power. So $f$ is irreducible.
It is clearly not inseparable because $f ^\prime (x)$ do not share root with $f$.

See the discussion here on being irreducible over $\Bbb F_p$. It should not have a root, then it is irreducible. We have $D(f)=pX^{p-1}-1=-1$, so it is separable.
